# LiteralControls getting doubled onreload

Tags: c#

In the following code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
List<string> listSetValues = Class1.categories();

foreach (string strTemp in listSetValues)
{
    DIV1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<li>" + strTemp + "</li>"));
}
}
```

and class code is

```
protected static List<string> listSetValues = new List<string>();
public static List<string> categories()
{
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM category", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        listSetValues.Add(dr[0].ToString());
    }
    con.Close();
    return listSetValues;
}
```

Database table category consists of

```
Mobiles
DVD players
Cameras
Laptops
Televisions
```

Upon loading page all the above are being displayed in my website but on reloading the above five values are displayed for twice and on every reload the set of 5 values is keep on increasing.

Comment: @gdoron - I gave enough code! What else is missing in my code?

Comment: Are you not doing the data load using -> if(!IsPostBack) { // Load calls } in your page_load ???

Comment: @DnshPly9 - No. In just Page_Load function.

Comment: I was referring to the categories in categories.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<li>" + strTemp + "</li>"));

Comment: @NathanPitman - I am sorry for the confusion. Its a HTML DIV. I edited code now for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, You have to initialize the List each time upon loading.....

```
List<string> listSetValues =new List<string>();
listSetValues = Class1.categories();

foreach (string strTemp in listSetValues)
{
  categories.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<li>" + strTemp + "</li>"));
}
```

In method code,

```
public static List<string> categories()
{
    List<string> listSetValues = new List<string>();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM category", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
   {
      listSetValues.Add(dr[0].ToString());
   }
   con.Close();
   return listSetValues;
}
```

Comment: I think you have to initialize the categories control in top of foreach loop.....

Comment: What does 'categories' means?

Comment: I am sorry in `categories.Controls.Add` categories is a HTML DIV

Comment: I have figured out your problem....You have declared protected static List<string> listSetValues outside the method so, listSetValues values become static without initializing each time...You have declare listSetValues inside the method....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is each time you are making a postback to the server, you are adding the same items to your list and binding your control to the data.

To avoid this what you must do is, in your Page_Load method

call the loading data method like

```
 if(!IsPostBack)
 {
     LoadData();
 }
```

What this will do is bind your list only once, i.e when your page is loaded for the first time and will not bind on other postback to the server.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No! this is not the issue. Actually not on postback but the issue is with Page_Load. Each time Page_Loads the values are appending to DIV `categories`

Comment: here each time page is loaded the list items are added to the div and hence duplicate data. either you must clear all the div items before the foreach look using something like div.items.clear() and then this will work. The best thing is call the lines of code shown above in Page_Load in a if(!IsPostBack) { // all code here } and this will only bind your data once, no repetition of categories.

Comment: None of these worked. I tried write code in if(!IsPostBack) and also Div1.Controls.Clear(); both failed :(

Comment: Ohh missed it!!! Yes it wont! because you have declared the variable listSetValues as static. In your class method you must set the listSetValues = null before adding categories to it. One more thing why are you keeping the methods static???? try avoiding it